# Backup retention for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have databases on Postgres 10 on some CentOS 7 servers.
It's necessary to maintain different database backup copies and diverse retention requirements for critical PostgreSQL instances.

Rman provides retention for Oracle backups, administrators are able to set retention for days or months for example. And after the retention period the expired backup would be deleted.

What PostgreSQL's native package/software are able to do this?

Comment: Does anyone recommend any solution for this purpose?